# Change member nickname on join (Discord.js)

Tags: discord, discord.js

so I have a huge problem with people joining my server with a hoisted name "! Name" which puts them at the top of the member's list, and they can advertise their servers. I am trying to change their nickname to something random when they join. I am using discord.js. I think it would be something like "message.member.setNickname" but I could be wrong, if you can help it would be appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To detect incoming users, you should listen to the [`guildMemberAdd`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/Client?scrollTo=e-guildMemberAdd) event, which passes a [`GuildMember`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/GuildMember) as a parameter. `GuildMembers` don't have a `username` property, so you'll have to use [`GuildMember#user`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/GuildMember?scrollTo=user) to convert it to a [`User`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/User), and then check [`User#username`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/User?scrollTo=username).

If the username starts with a `!`, you can use [`GuildMember#setNickname`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/GuildMember?scrollTo=setNickname) to change it.

```js
client.on('guildMemberAdd', (member) => {
 if (member.user.username.startsWith('!')) {
  member.setNickname('...');
  // code...
 }
});
```

It might also be a good idea to listen to the [`guildMemberUpdate`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/Client?scrollTo=e-guildMemberUpdate) event to see if a member ever changes their nickname *after* joining to something you wouldn't want.